# How to modify a Label from another Controller (lookup + update)?

Tags: javafx-2

I have created a tabPane. Under each tab, I have included () an fxml to show the actual session user, with this code :

home-tab.fxml has this line :

```
<fx:include fx:id="topTab" source="../top-tab.fxml"/>
```

top-tab.fxml :

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="20.0"  prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="wuendo.client.TopTabController">
   <children>
      <HBox id="hbox_top" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <Label id="label_session" prefHeight="20.0" text="SESSION : " />
         <Label fx:id="sessionLabel" prefHeight="20.0" text="" />  
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

TopTabController.java :

```
@FXML public Label sessionLabel;
```

HomeTabController.java :

```
@FXML private TopTabController topTabController;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  URL location = getClass().getResource("../top-tab.fxml");
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(location);
  AnchorPane root = null;
  try {
     root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
  }  catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(HomeTabController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  topTabController = (TopTabController) fxmlLoader.getController();

  Label txt = (Label) root.lookup("#sessionLabel");
  txt.setText("blabla");

  System.out.println("sessionLabel= " + topTabController.sessionLabel.getText());
}
```

When I execute this, the console prints "blabla", but the label is not modified in the program (gui)

What do I have to do to see the value updated ?

Thank you all

Comment: `@FXML private TopTabController topTabController;` How did you relate the TopTabController with home-tab.fxml? Post it. Or try your app again after removing @FXML.

Comment: @UlukBiy, I followed Greg Brown's answer in this post : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10412389, where he explains that the topTabController will automatically be created and populated (if I understood correctly!). 

I have updated the code to be more explicit. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` is already created the TopTabController while the home-tab.fxml is being loaded. And it is the rendered one in the scene. However you are creating/loading another instance of TopTabController which is not added to the any scene. And you are changing the text of the label in the second one. The correct approach is to modify the already loaded 1st instance and not to load other one:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    topTabController.sessionLabel.setText("Real blabla");
    System.out.println("sessionLabel= " + topTabController.sessionLabel.getText());
}
```

Side note, The link you provided in the comment was useful.